# Eclipse set breakpoint for fortran project

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran

I have a simple fortran project on Eclipse with two source files `program.f90` and `KASTBitmap.f90` which contains some functions I am currently writing as a library for bitmap images includes loading/saving/manipulating images.

I am trying to set a break point in `KASTBitmap.f90` and when I start the debugger I get this error:

```
At line 18 of file ../KASTBitmap.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'FaceImg5.bmp')
Fortran runtime error: Non-existing record number
```

any ideas or hints are appreciated.

Comment: How do you start the debugger?

Comment: I start the debugger from eclipse menu: run->debug

Comment: debugger print start up messages I have in the program.f90 before calling the function in KASTBitmap.f90 which causes the error shown above.